# XML DOM Hierarchy

Tags: xml, dom

Consider the following XML file:

```
<employees>
    <employee>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <lastName>Smith</lastName>
        <ssn>123456789</ssn>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

What is the DOM hierarchy of the XML?
What is the first child of employees? Is it blank (text node) or employee?

Just want to be clear: Even if there is no text in between the tags, is it still considered as text node with null value?

Comment: Why a “null value”? You have a line break (one or two characters) there, and then indentation (spaces or tabs most likely) before the `<firstName>` start tag – _that’s_ the content of the text node that is the first child of `employee`.

Comment: Ohkay! Thank you very much. I am now very clear about the concept.